# SpringMVC request parameter conversion

Tags: java, spring-mvc, propertyeditor

I can use property editors in SpringMVC to do custom conversion of a request parameter. For example to convert a request parameter to an instance of `Foo` below

```
public class Foo {
    private val;

    public Foo(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }        
    public getVal() {
        return val;
    }     
}
```

I can define a property editor

```
public class FooPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    void setAsText(String paramValue) {
        value = new Foo(paramValue);
    }

    public String getAsText() {
        return ((Foo) value).getVal();
    }
}
```

and register this to perform conversion from a String to a Foo

```
public class CustomEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry reg) {
       reg.registerCustomEditor(Foo.class, new FooPropertyEditor());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use a property editor to convert a multi-valued parameter such as

```
foo=foo1&foo=foo2&foo=foo3
```

to a `List<Foo>`. Assuming I've already written an appropriate property editor `FooListPropertyEditor`, I don't think I can register it using:

```
public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry reg) {
   reg.registerCustomEditor(List<Foo>.class, new FooListPropertyEditor());
}
```

Because AFAIK `List<Foo>.class` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

take a look at **org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomCollectionEditor**